# What is the difference between Application State and Application Session?

Tags: session, system, state

What is the difference between Application State and Application Session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A session is usually for a user and only lasts from when they login to when they logout (or get timed out). Application State has a much longer lifetime, is shared between all users, and is only cleared when the process is restarted.

Comment: @PPC-Coader can i ask ? what do you mean by "process is restarted" ? which process ?

Comment: @Hardik What I mean is that the IIS worker process is recycled, or the app pool is restarted.